# Program execution freezes when using a different thread to imshow Image

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, opencv, python

The below code snippet displays same image one after the other

```
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I except the below code snippet to work in the same manner

```
def show():
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

thread = threading.Thread(target = show)
thread.start()
thread.join()

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but there seem to be some kind of problem with the second `imshow` statement. I used print statements to find out that program freezes at second `imshow` statement. Can anyone tell me why does that happen?

## Edit:

I found few similar issues on internet, and most of them say that `cv2.imshow` should be used with main thread only. I guess cv2.imshow works only with one thread be it the main thread or any other thread which you create. Calling this method in any other thread will freeze the execution.

Answer (score 0):

**On the official Open CV documentation:**

cv2.waitKey() is a keyboard binding function. Its argument is the time in milliseconds. The function waits for specified milliseconds for any keyboard event. If you press any key in that time, the program continues. ***If 0 is passed, it waits indefinitely for a key stroke.*** It can also be set to detect specific key strokes like, if key a is pressed etc which we will discuss below.

**Another important note:**

- You can create as many windows as you wish, but with different window
  names.
- Additionally Passing Keystrokes to Threaded modules is not a good
  practice especially on windows due to GIL(Global Interpreter Lock)
  constraints.

Comment: I know how waitKey works, that's not the issue. Would you mind trying my code snippets and see what's the bug?